# Angular CLI on HTTPS - can't install CI as root

Tags: npm, angular-cli, n

I need to have my angular app over https port 443. To do that, I need to run `ng` as root. However, I can not get Angular CLI to install as root. Any suggestions?

```
root@develop:~# n v9.4.0

     install : node-v9.4.0
       mkdir : /root/n/n/versions/node/9.4.0
       fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v9.4.0/node-v9.4.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
######################################################################### 100.0%
   installed : v9.4.0

root@develop:~# npm install -g @angular/cli
/root/n/bin/ng -> /root/n/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> @angular/cli@8.2.0 postinstall /root/n/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

sh: 1: node: Permission denied
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! @angular/cli@8.2.0 postinstall: `node ./bin/postinstall/script.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @angular/cli@8.2.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-08-07T14_07_14_142Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default npm takes some steps to avoid running scripts as root. You can override this with `--unsafe-perm`:

```
# npm install -g --unsafe-perm @angular/cli
```

(As an aside: you do not need to install angular as root to run your eventual service as root, but that is a longer answer with more context needed.)

Comment: Thanks. Since port 443 is a privileged port and requires root, how else would I run this without root?

Comment: You need privilege when you launch your service listening on port 443, but you can build your application as an ordinary user. In a Dockerfile see the USER instruction. Since you are going to start and finish as root, you might not consider it worthwhile though! Best practices: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices#user